# remove a top link from an handler

Tags: magento-1.9, layout, toplinks, update-handle

I need to remove this link only from a `custom handle`. The handle is working, but I cannot find the right syntax to remove the link, maybe `removeLinkByUrl` or `byName`.

```
<reference name="top.links"><action method="addLink" translate="label title" module="customer"><label>Faq</label><url>faq</url><title>Faq</title><prepare>true</prepare><urlParams/><position>200</position><liParams/><aParams/></action></reference>
```

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`top.links` stands for `Mage_Page_Block_Template_Links`. There you can see a method to remove link based on url. Method name is `removeLinkByUrl()`.

So try this.

```
<custom_layout_handle>
    <reference name="top.links>
        <action method="removeLinkByUrl">
             <url>faq</url>
        </action>
    </reference>
</custom_layout_handle>
```